# Impossible to put an image next to the table using domPDF

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have the table shown below; what I want is to insert an image next to the table in my pdf view. I am using domPDF.

I try to use display inline-block but domPDF doesn't support display inline.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

table th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table td {
  text-align: right;
}

table td h3 {
  color: #ab5401;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
}

table .no {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  background: #ad9c82;
}

table .desc {
  text-align: left;
}

table .total .total-div {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

table .total {
  background: #ad9c82;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

table td.total {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

table tbody tr:last-child td {
  border: none;
}

table tfoot td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

table tfoot tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

table tfoot tr:last-child td {
  color: #ab5401;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ab5401;
}

table tfoot tr td:first-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="no">#</th>
      <th class="desc">DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th class="total">TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="no">01</td>
      <td class="desc">
        <h3>Website Design</h3>Creating a recognizable design solution based on the company's existing visual identity</td>
      <td class="total">$1,200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="no">02</td>
      <td class="desc">
        <h3>Website Development</h3>Developing a Content Management System-based Website</td>
      <td class="total">$3,200.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">SUBTOTAL</td>
      <td>$5,200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">TAX 25%</td>
      <td>$1,300.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">GRAND TOTAL</td>
      <td>$6,500.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

While the image for placeholder is the following:

`<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Image example">`

I tried to add it but it is always placed under the table, not next to it as I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding good old floats.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

table th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table td {
  text-align: right;
}

table td h3 {
  color: #ab5401;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
}

table .no {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  background: #ad9c82;
}

table .desc {
  text-align: left;
}

table .total .total-div {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

table .total {
  background: #ad9c82;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

table td.total {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

table tbody tr:last-child td {
  border: none;
}

table tfoot td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

table tfoot tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

table tfoot tr:last-child td {
  color: #ab5401;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ab5401;
}

table tfoot tr td:first-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 65%;float:left;">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="no">#</th>
      <th class="desc">DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th class="total">TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="no">01</td>
      <td class="desc">
        <h3>Website Design</h3>Creating a recognizable design solution based on the company's existing visual identity</td>
      <td class="total">$1,200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="no">02</td>
      <td class="desc">
        <h3>Website Development</h3>Developing a Content Management System-based Website</td>
      <td class="total">$3,200.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">SUBTOTAL</td>
      <td>$5,200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">TAX 25%</td>
      <td>$1,300.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">GRAND TOTAL</td>
      <td>$6,500.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<div style="width: 30%;float:left;">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Image example" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```